# Gives 404 Error when a file exists in Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, http-status-code-404

When I upload a HTML or PHP file to my server, it won't be loaded from the web and gives following error:
[image: Error]

I check the permissions - it's said that it can be read by all users:

```
$ ls -l /var/www/pros.sbs/newhtml.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100 Jun 10 19:33 /var/www/pros.sbs/newhtml.html
```

So what's the problem?